# Why can't I initialize a typedef struct string or char as normally?

Tags: c++, string, struct, char, typedef

I'm begginer in programming and C++.

Programming on Linux, I am creating a typedef struct as below:

```
typedef struct {

    char id[10];
    string name[20];    

}Employee;
```

Usually, when not using struct, I initialize string char doing:

```
char id[10]="ID02093";
string name="Joe";
```

So, why can't I initialize char id and string name of the Employee struct as below?:

```
Employee salesManager;
salesManager.id="ID02093";
salesManager.name="Joe";
```

I'm getting this errors from the g++ compiler:

> "incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [8]’ to ‘char [9]’ 
>   salesManager.id="ID02093";" incompatible types in assignment of ‘const
>   char [4]’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string [20] {aka
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string [20]}’  salesManager.name="Joe";

What's the right way to initialize string and char of typedef struct elements out of the typedef struct declaration?

Comment: Because `salesManager.id="ID02093";` is not initialisation - it's an attempt at assignment.

Comment: Hint: Initialization only happens on the line the variable is declared on.  After that it is assignment.

Comment: and how to assign values to those char and string after declaration?

Comment: `string name[20];` is 20 strings. Do you want 20 names?

Comment: This looks more like C than (modern) C++.

Comment: You probably should use std::string for both and avoid char arrays.

Comment: @drescherjm uppppsss what a mistake!! sorry
And what about char?

Comment: `char` is a single character. You probably need more than that to identify an employee so an array is better however again I  would just use std::string for both.

Comment: @drescherjm
char name; //is single character
but char name[10] is a string. Isn't that?

Comment: ***char name[10] is a string*** No its a character array. or c-string. In `c++` std::string is preferred. You would not have a problem with the assignment if you used a `std::string`. However a character array is not assignable. You need to copy it manually.

Comment: @PlàcidMasvidal: "`char name[10]` is a string" -- No, it isn't. It's an array. It may or may not *contain* a string. A *string* in C is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".

Comment: Your question is tagged C, but you're compiling with g++ (a C++ compiler), and you accepted an answer that uses the C++-specific type `std::string`. They're two different languages. In C++, the `typedef` is superfluous. In C, it's mostly superfluous as well, but if you define `struct Employee { ... }` you have to refer to the type as `struct Employee` rather than just `Employee`.

Comment: It was originally tagged as `c++`

Comment: @KeithThompson: The question text is using `std::string`, just not explicitly stated. The C++ tag should come back, the C tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialization and assignment are two distinct (but similar) things.

You can initialize an array by providing a value for it when you declare/define it.

You cannot assign to an array.

You can *copy* a value into an array using `memcpy` or `strcpy`:

```
char name[20];
strcpy(name, "Test";
```

But for your purposes, you can initialize the array as part of the initialization of the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char id[10];          
    char name[20];
} Employee;
Employee salesManager = {
    "A12345678",
    "Test"
};
/* OR */
Employee salesManager = {
    .id = "A12345678",
    .name = "Test"
};
```

Since you're asking about C++ rather than C, it's probably better to use `std::string` rather than raw character arrays. `std::string` is a lot more flexible: you can assign values, including string literals, to `std::string` objects.

Comment: I don't know how to use std::string
I'm begginer, in class we didn't study it yet.
How to use it in this case?

Comment: @PlàcidMasvidal: How to use `std::string` is too big a topic to be addressed in a comment. I presume you'll get to it in your class soon enough. If you want to start early, cppreference.com is a good reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use string in both cases, and use OOP instead of typedef. But try this code bellow, should work fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {

    string id;
    string name;    

} Employee;


int main() {
    Employee salesManager;
    salesManager.id = "A12345678";
    salesManager.name = "Test";

    cout << "Id: " << salesManager.id << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << salesManager.name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to up vote this but the rest of the c-isms need to be removed.  You can also initialize both elements when you declare `salesManager` instead of assigning later.

Comment: [There's no need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c) for `typedef struct { ... } Employee;`, when `struct Employee { ... };` will do just fine.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just did in this way to follow his logic.

Comment: "use OOP instead of typedef" you are mixing things. `typedef` in that place is just unnecessary and has nothing to do with OOP or no OOP

Answer (score 0):

#### You cannot assign to an array of `char`

Considering this line:

> ```
> salesManager.id="ID02093";
> ```

You are allowed to initialize an array of `char` with a string literal as a convenience allowed by the syntax C++ inherited from C. However, you are not permitted to use assignment with an array. Which is why you got this error:

> `incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [8]’ to ‘char [9]’ salesManager.id="ID02093";`

Instead, you have to copy the data into the array.

#### You cannot assign to an array of `string`

Considering this line

> ```
> salesManager.name="Joe";
> ```

The reason this failed is because you had declared `name` to be an array as well.

> ```
> typedef struct {
>
>     char id[10];
>     string name[20];    
>
> }Employee;
> ```

This explains why you got this error:

> `incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [4]’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string [20] {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string [20]}’ salesManager.name="Joe";`

You likely did not mean to declare `name` to be an array.

#### Avoid using anonymous classes

A `typedef` name given to an anonymous class type has slightly different semantics from a class name. Since the differences are tricky, it is best to avoid using anonymous classes if it is not contained within a class itself.